# How do I create and add a new table everytime I search with a new tag, without reloading my side?

Tags: php, html, datatables

My html including a search button, which posts a tag to an API which returns the info that I flood my table with: called aktie.php. I'm sure that I should use some ajax, java, jQuery or w.e. But I'm lost in how to do this. hope you guys have a solution?

```
<?php
include ('./stock_table.php');
?>

<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="post">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Søg" 
action="./baseconfig.php" name="post_tag">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" 
name="post_search">Søg</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>    

<div class="d-flex align-items-start mt-5">
    <div class="container-xxl mt-2 d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-5" style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <?php
            echo build_table($data);
        ?>
    </div>
```

My baseconfig.php file includes a variable that updates when a tag is entered in the search button

```
$tag = "NVO";

if (isset($_POST['post_search'])) {
    $tag = $_POST['post_tag'];        
}
```

I build my table in a php file: stock_table.php

```
<?php
include('baseconfig.php');

function build_table($data, 
$subheadlines4){
// start table
$html = '<div class="container">';  
$html .= '<table class="table table-responsive" style="overflow-x:auto;">';

$html .= '<thead class="thead-dark">';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<th colspan="10" class="text-center"">';
foreach($data[1] as $key=>$value) {
    $html .= htmlspecialchars($value) . " ";
}

// finish table and return it
$html .= '</table>';
$html .= '</div>';
return $html;
};
?>
```

Comment: You have to search about AJAX.

Comment: yeah I figured, but i've tried and failed several times. So I hoped that you guys could kick me  in the right direction :)

Comment: The only result I did get using AJAX , was to overwrite the old table and adding a new table with the same results

Comment: Note that the `action` attribute has nothing to do in the `input` tag. It's a `form` tag attribute.

Comment: Okay thanks for the update :)